# Hide ECB item in SharePoint 2013 list view with grouping implemented on it

Tags: 2013, list-view, grouping

I came across this answer - https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/115553/32642

It works perfectly if list view don't have grouping. 
But in case of grouping it is not working. Can please any one help me out in this scenario.

Thanks in advance.