# How to remove Alert me, Share with link from ECB menu?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, web-part, list-view

[image]

I want to remove items from workflow.

Comment: Did you check this http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/114587/remove-item-from-ecb-in-sharepoint-2013

Comment: Here is one more link. http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/105267/hide-ecb-item-in-a-sharepoint-2013-list/115553#115553